# Drivers completely messed up after the last Ubuntu update

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, audio, kernel-modules, software-updates

Ma laptop (Dell Vostro 7590 with a i7 9th gen) was working completely fine with Ubuntu but the last update from Ubuntu completely messed my drivers. After the reboot I had no sound. I fixed this problem by blocking the snd_soc_skl driver and using the snd_hda_intel instead.

However, my microphone is still not working and I can't use bluetooth (every devices get disconnected after 1 second) ...I really need to fix those issues. With the ongoing pandemic, I am working from home and skype is not an option.
here is what i get from `lspci -v | grep "audio"` :

```
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0924
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 156
    Memory at ed318000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at ed100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev
```

My Kernel version is : `uname -a`

`Linux elias-Vostro-7590 5.3.0-42-generic #34~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 13:42:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 0):

Booting to the previous kernel version solves the problem.

Comment: add why that is, how did you investigate and such details